# Linking to specific AJAX data on WordPress page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

On my WordPress website, I'm writing a plugin with a world map that loads a particular post depending on what region is clicked using AJAX. I'd like to include links within the main navigation that point to the map page with a region's post already displayed (ex: the link titled "Middle East" would direct the user to the map page with the Middle East post already displayed). I'm trying to use location.hash but I don't totally understand how it works. Here is my code:

start.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Added code based on jetlej's answer
    jQuery('#vmap').ready( function(event, code, region) {
        $.ajax(get_data.ajaxurl, {
            data: {region: region, 'action': 'get_post_data'},
            dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#post").html(response);
                    location.hash = region;
                }
        });
    });

    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        // more map config options...
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
        {
            if (location.hash) {
                location.hash.replace("#","")+".html"
            }

            $.ajax(get_data.ajaxurl, {
                data: {region: region, 'action': 'get_post_data'},
                dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#post").html(response);
                        location.hash = region;
                }
            });

        }  
    });
});
```

index.php:

```
class Post{
    function get_post( $ID ){
        $html = '';
        $post = get_post( $ID );
        if( $post ) {
            $html = $post->post_title;
            $html .= wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
            $html .= $post->post_content;
        }
        return $html;
    }
}

function get_post_data(){

    $post = new Post();
    $result = '';

      // Swtich based on region
      switch($_REQUEST['region']) {
        //Europe
        case 'Russia':
        case 'Albania':
            $result = $post->get_post( 405 );
          break;

        //Africa
        case 'Congo':
        case 'Nigeria':
            $result = $post->get_post( 388 );
          break;

      echo json_encode($result);
      die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_post_data', 'get_post_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_data', 'get_post_data');
```

And my links look like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/where-we-serve/#Russia">Europe</a>
```

When I click the link, it takes me to the map page but it's in its default state with no posts displayed. I'm getting the hash values in the URL when I click the map, but they don't seem to actually have any effect on the state of the page. Is this an issue with how I'm using location.hash, an issue with the link, or is this just the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be checking for the hash value on each page load. You're only checking if the map is clicked.

For getting the map to show the region from the hash, you just need to use your map plugin's built-in 'selectedRegion' parameter.

Eg.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        region = null;
        // If there is a hash, then grab it and update the page to reflect that region
        if(location.hash){

            // Remove the '#' from the hash
            region = location.hash.split('#')[1];

            // Update #post with the region post info
            $.ajax(get_data.ajaxurl, {
                data: {region: region, 'action': 'get_post_data'},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#post").html(response);
                }
            });    

        }

        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            // Set the pre-selected to region to that hash, or null if there is no hash
            selectedRegion: region,
            onRegionClick: function(element, code, region){
                if (location.hash) {
                    location.hash.replace("#","")+".html"
                }

                $.ajax(get_data.ajaxurl, {
                    data: {region: region, 'action': 'get_post_data'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#post").html(response);
                        location.hash = region;
                    }
                });
            }  
        });
    });
```

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of what the function might look like?

Comment: Does it currently work correctly if you click on a location on the map?

Comment: Yes. You can take a look [here](http://dev.bibleleague.org/where-we-serve/) if you want.

Comment: Just edited the answer :) All you need to do is replace that first code block you included with what I pasted in. You just need to figure out how to grab the region variable from the map. Should be in the documentation of the plugin that you're using!

Comment: The only way I know to access 'region' is within the function(event, code, region) that the JQVMap API provides. I'm updating the first code block in my question to show how I've implemented your code (no guarantees this is right). Now when I reload the map page it shows #undefined in the URL. When I try to navigate to the map page using the anchor tag shown in my question, the URL briefly displays #Russia and then changes to #undefined. The post does not load with the page as intended.

Comment: What plugin are you using for the map? The code you create from my answer will not work since it's not actually using the plugin.

Comment: I'm writing this AS a plugin using a jQuery API called [JQVMaps](http://jqvmap.com). The map is not a WP plugin, it's a part of the plugin I'm writing.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand. I just updated the code, so you should be able to just copy/paste that in and have it work.

Comment: Awesome, that works great now. I was getting ready to try another switch based on the map regions, but the simple if statement with location.hash does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: So glad it worked! Have fun with your continual exploration of jQuery. It only gets more enjoyable as you understand it more.